# Changing the order of xaxis affecting the data

Tags: python, plotly

I am visualizing a dataset with the Weekday as x-axis component.

```
fig = go.Figure()
res = {}
for month, data in flights.items():
    res[month] = fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=data, 
                            x= df["WEEKDAY"].unique(), 
                            mode='lines',
                            opacity=0.3                     
                 ))
```

However, if I let my code run normally, the graph starts on Thursday ( and not at the beginning of the week). That's why I included a piece of code from another question that's supposed to change the order of the x-axis items.

```
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray= ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'])
```

After that, the order is right but the data isnt matching the right days anymore and one timestamp seems broken. What to do now?

[image]

Comment: what is `flights`? (a **dict** of lists ?)  why are you creating a **dict** of figures with what will be identical figures (you only have one `go.Figure()`.  I assume `df` is a dataframe, but how is it related to `data` that provides the values for **y**.  I can only assume that `data` is a **list** / array of 7 values

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change the type graph and you can add - animation_frame= name column